# Isotope: first item sometimes not linkable

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using Isotope and running into a strange problem: in some browsers the first item is not linkable.  It is happening in all versions of IE and Firefox on a mac. I have filters on the page and if you click one, then the first item becomes linkable.  But it's not initially.

I saw another post about the first item and the solution had something to do with the column width...but in my case I have it changing, as this is a responsive site.

Here's the code:

```
var $container = $('#project-thumbs');          
var $default_filter = ".featured";                  

$container.isotope({
    animationEngine: 'best-available',
    filter: $default_filter,
    itemSelector : '.thumb',
    // disable resizing
    resizable: false
});

// update columnWidth on window resize
$(window).smartresize(function(){
  $container.isotope({

  });
});
```

Any thoughts?

UPDATE 1: 
Actually, it looks like it is in all browsers (PC Firefox and Chrome, too).

I did just discover if I change my thumbs (the elements that are being moved about) to have "position:relative" using Firebug, the first item becomes linkable.  However, the plugin is adding the "position:absolute" (and probably needs to) so setting this style myself gets overwritten.  But maybe it is a clue?

UPDATE 2: 
I am getting closer.  I think this is part of the issue.  What I am doing is, instead of displaying all items initially, I am displaying a subset.  If you look at the HTML, the first item in the list is actually hidden because it is not part of my subset. However, it's link seems to be taking precedence over the "visible" first item.....

UPDATE 3: 
More details... in the meantime, I was trying to figure out why some text was looking fuzzy on this page on an Android smart phone.  I found that adding transformsEnabled: false fixed the problem.  However, having that in there caused this "non-linking" problem to happen more often -- and in all browsers.  It's almost like the items aren't being given the right z-index or something.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've got a workaround that does the job, although it is not the most elegant option.

Instead of filtering the initial view using the isotope plugin, I just have it load everything.  Then, I use regular jQuery to trigger the click event on the filter link on the page for the category I wanted initially loaded.

```
// delay, then trigger click on Featured
$('#sub-nav a.featured').delay(5000).trigger('click');
```

As I noted above, I had noticed that once you start clicking on different filters, the issue went away.  So this effectively initiates the click that helps avoid the situation.

Still would be interested in a fix if there is one!

Thanks.